# TVML linking of buttons

Tags: tvml

I have a very short question, that might be trivial to some of you guys, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation of TVML.
And since I'm usually a designer I don't have to deal much with code.

I used the productBundleTemplate to build the main page of the app.
Here is an example:

```
> <section>
>         <lockup>
>           <img src="${this.BASEURL}resources/test.jpg" width="332" height="500" />
>           <title class="showTextOnHighlight"></title>
>           <overlay>
>             <progressBar value="0.1" />
>           </overlay>
>           <relatedContent>
>             <infoTable>
>               <header>
>                 <title>Test</title>
>               </header>
>               <info>
>                 <header>
>                   <title></title>
>                 </header>
>                 <description allowsZooming="true">This is great</description>
>               </info>
>             </infoTable>
>           </relatedContent>
>         </lockup>
```

Now I want to link this product to a different product page. What code do I need to use for that?

My last question would be, how do I link buttons to other content. My guess it will be the same way but just to make sure I mention it as well.
I'm sure there must be some kind of reference in the TVML documentation but I was unable to find any. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: I'm a little bit lost any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i think i can help. What you need to have is you need a reference to the new product page you would like to load from the is page. So for example:
 < 
lockup template=http://...url to your template here...>

> ```
>       <img src="${this.BASEURL}resources/test.jpg" width="332" height="500" />
>       <title class="showTextOnHighlight"></title>
>       <overlay>
> ```

in your **presenter.js** file (which I'm sure you have) you need to have a function that loads this template when the image is selected.

finally in your main.js or application.js (whatever you called it) you must  add an eventlistener to the document. This should load the file.

if everything I just said sound like gibberish, check out and DOWNLOAD apple's sample tvml project. It helps to show the basics of how to start navigating through templates.  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html
Hope this helps bud.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "link this product to a different product page", I presume you mean that when the user moves the selection to that item and then selects it (clicks the touchpad on the Siri remote, presses select on the IR remote, taps the screen in the Remote iOS app), you want the current display that's based on the productBundleTemplate to go away and a new display that's based on a productTemplate to display instead.  Further, by "link buttons to other content", I assume you mean something similar, where navigating to the button and then selecting it goes to a different page.

There are three parts to that.  "Out of the box", selecting items doesn't do anything except jiggle the UI a bit.  (It's like if web browsers didn't have a built in concept of following hrefs when users clicked on links.)

So the first part is, you've got to set up a JavaScript event handler for the "select" event.  For both lockups inside of lists and for buttons, "select" is the event that's fired when the user does that.  There are other events, but I think "select" is the one you want for those two things.

The second part is, you've got to decide where to go.  There are a few ways you could do this, but the easiest trick is to add a custom attribute to the TVML element that receives the "select" event.  Then you can dereference the element from the event in the event handler, read the custom attribute, and you're off and running.  If your product pages are statically generated, you might just include an actual URL, perhaps even using "href" as an attribute.  If your product pages are dynamically generated, you could define a "productid" attribute.

The third part is to get the new content into JavaScript's memory and then put it in front of the user with methods on the "navigationDocument" object.  If you're dealing with TVML files that already exist somewhere, like in the app bundle or your server, then you'd fetch it by making an XMLHttpRequest call.  If you're dealing with TVML that's dynamically built up entirely within your JavaScript, well, you need to write code to do that (but it doesn't have to be very complicated).

The simplest example I've seen of the "existing TVML files with URLs" approach is here:

https://gist.github.com/rayh/d023aeba28a25ed7f7f2

The simplest example I've seen of the "create the TVML dynamically" approach is the "createAlert" function in the following tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/114886/beginning-tvos-development-with-tvml-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) framework, your requirement is very simple to achieve. All you need to do is add `data-href-page` attribute to your selectable element with value as the name of your previously created page. The framework will automatically navigate to the page on selection. Here's a snippet to help you get started.

```
// your template
var homepageDoc = `<document>
                    <productBundleTemplate>
                        /* usual tvml elements */
                            <lockup data-href-page="details">
                                /* usual tvml elements */
                            </lockup>
                    </productBundleTemplate>
                </document>`;
// create pages
ATV.Page.create({
    name: 'homepage',
    template: function(data) {
        return homepageDoc;
    }
});
ATV.Page.create({
    name: 'details',
    /* and other usual params */
});

// later in your application, navigate to your initial page
ATV.Navigation.navigate('homepage');
```

*Disclaimer: I am the creator and maintainer of [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) and as of writing this answer, it is the **only** JavaScript framework available for Apple TV development using TVML and TVJS. Hence I could provide references only from this framework. The answer should not be mistaken as a biased opinion.*

Answer (score 0):

To do this for a TVML app, you need a little javascript, and a little TVML.

If you work through Creating Dynamic Page Content guide of Apple's TVML reference, (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/ExpandingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016718-CH3-SW2) in the second section (Navigating Between Pages) it tells you what you need to do exactly.

Briefly, you need a function in your javascript like this (taken from their sample code in the link above):

```
function getDocument(url) {
    var templateXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    templateXHR.responseType = "document";
    templateXHR.addEventListener("load", function() {pushDoc(templateXHR.responseXML);}, false);
    templateXHR.open("GET", url, true);
    templateXHR.send();
}
```

and then in your TVML you need a button or something for the user to press.

```
<button onselect="getDocument('templates/NextPage.xml')">
        <text>Next page</text>
</button>
```

the key is to add the onselect="getDocument('link to new tvml page')" , which comes from the code you added to your javascript.